# Is it possible to reorder my workspaces?

Tags: compiz, workspaces, customization, productivity

Recently I found that on a macbook it is possible to drag the multiple desktops to change their order.

**The ideal solution** would be to, while on the compiz Expo mode, be able to just drag and move a whole workspace together with all the windows it contains to another position.

Searching for this I found [an ubuntu braistorm idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/19039/) that describes exactly what I would like to be able to do!

**A work around** using a command line script could also be used maybe..?

Any ideas?

[image: Reorder viewports]

Comment: Cairo-dock makes this possible. Switcher-applet of cairo dock has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for an answer to this question for quite a long time but recently I had stumbled upon the answer myself.

**Solution**:

When you hit `Windows+S` to go to workspace switcher, in that view you can quickly double click on any visible window in any workspace and drag that window to any other workspace.

This way you can re-order workspaces.

I am a huge user of workspaces on a daily basis and I find this little trick very helpful to re-order my workspaces.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: This you describe is to move individual windows (application). The question is how to move one entire workspace at once.

Comment: even if it does not answer the original question, I found your suggestion very helpful. FYI I am not even using ubuntu here, it's Pantheon (elementary os' desktop environment) on debian. But still, your solution works on it too

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is: no

---

The long answer is: Do you really need this feature? If so the go to compiz site and beg them to add it. (or ubutus site) You can otherwise use: super w to spread out al the windows and see them. You can also use "clone output" that will transform the Window to a lillte icon that you can move to another work-space. But I think that at this state the work-spaces is static. Hope it helped.

Comment: You may want to edit this post to include information (or link to information) on how to properly submit feature requests.

Comment: yes I need it. I already commented on the idea on the ubuntu brainstorm to help promote it.. begging seemed a little too much.. It seems you missed the point: a want to reorder the workspaces and not the windows in them. thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing helpfull... I was just trying to give (my personal) sulotion or work around of the problem. You will just have to wait for somebody to write a script or for ubuntu to add this feature. Or do I your self and help other people that need this feature. And you have the cairo dock and pear os (that i have not tested) they mait have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but I found a solution that I hope is useful to others that stumble upon here:

https://github.com/smmr0/gnome-reorder-workspaces

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3685/reorder-workspaces/

Comment: what a drive down the memory lane viewing my question! I've since then moved to tiling window managers, using awesome wm for a couple of years now and I love it.